# Enable Textbox if any selection is made in a combobox in Access

Tags: ms-access, combobox, vba

Hey I am trying to get a textbox to enable based on if someone selects any value in a combobox it does not have to be a specific one just any value. This is the code I have so far and I am getting a Type Mismatch error, but my field type is short text.

```
Private Sub cmbOwner2_Click()
If Me.cmbOwner2.Value Then
Me.txtOwner2.Enabled = True
Else
Me.txtOwner2.Enabled = False
End If
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance! Also, I am using VBA if thats not obvious lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
Private Sub cmbOwner2_Click()
If Me.cmbOwner2.Value <> "" Then
Me.txtOwner2.Enabled = True
Else
Me.txtOwner2.Enabled = False
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You rock! Thanks so much :)

Comment: you're welcome, and if your question is answered please use the tick :)

Comment: I will it told me I had to wait 6 more minutes for some reason.

Comment: Ok, I guess in case of editing or similar reasons. If you need further help any time, don't hesitate to contact us. :)

Comment: I cant ask more than one question on one page right?

Comment: Of course you can ask more than one question. But use one paige for a single problem only. e.g. don't ask multiple questions to different macros, when they don't rely to each other.

Comment: Ok cool I asked another question on another page not getting what I need though :/ lol